# How can i stay in the same location after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax call, How can i retain after page reload

I tried this but it reload the whole page i need to stay in the same location. Is there anyways to stay in the same location?

```
$('#updateAddressPrintFlagform').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let formData = $(this).serialize();

        $.post({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Address/Address/updateFlag",
            data: formData,
            success: window.location.reload(true)

        })
    })
```

Comment: you can use an anchor. But why use Javascript at all when you're just doing the same thing submitting a form would do? Another way would be to have a `success` method of your post and use that to update the page elements dynamically.

Comment: It makes no sense to use AJAX just to than reload a location. Simply, don't use `success: window.location.reload(true)` , rather: `success: function(res) { console.log(res); }`

Comment: @Cfreak when i used form submit it redirect me to another the action page i didn't want that, I want to update the flag just one field and post back the new value on the same page.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan here is the issue,in my view i have  `@Model.PrintFlag` as soon as i click submit button i want this field to be refreshed. does that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
$.post({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/Address/Address/updateFlag",
    data: formData,
    success: location.reload() //add this line instead
 })
```